# Merge 2 tables that have overlapping dates

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, merge

I have a **Customer** Table and a **Sales** Table. I have merged them together but they have overlapping dates. I need to get a cumulative total of the Sales, and the overlap is messing with my Cumulative Values. If Customer Date = Sales Date then Use Customer Date.  If `Customer Date >= Sales Date` then Use Sales Date.

I used this code to merge into a merge table:

```
USE Sales

INSERT INTO MERGE(FirstName, LastName, CustomerNo, DATE, Sales)
    SELECT A.SOURCE, A.FirstName, A.LastName, A.CustomerNo, A.DATE, A.sales
    FROM dbo.Customers AS A
    UNION
    SELECT B.FirstName B.LastName, B.CustomerNo, B.DATE, B.Sales
    FROM dbo.Sales AS B
;
```

It works but I can't seem to make the overlap part of the code work.

**Sample...**

```
+----------+-----------+----------+------------+-----------+-------+-----------------+
|  SOURCE  | FIRSTNAME | LASTNAME | CUSTOMERNO |   DATE    | SALES | CUMLATIVE_SALES |
+----------+-----------+----------+------------+-----------+-------+-----------------+
| CUSTOMER | Tom       | White    |      65123 | 3/1/2017  | 38.78 |                 |
| CUSTOMER | Tom       | White    |      65123 | 3/20/2017 |   128 |          166.78 |
| CUSTOMER | Tom       | White    |      65123 | 4/8/2017  |   256 |          422.78 |
| CUSTOMER | Tom       | White    |      65123 | 4/27/2017 |   105 |          527.78 |
| CUSTOMER | Tom       | White    |      65123 | 5/16/2017 |    78 |          605.78 |
| CUSTOMER | Tom       | White    |      65123 | 6/4/2017  |    15 |          620.78 |
| SALES    | Tom       | White    |      65123 | 5/16/2017 |    78 |          698.78 |
| SALES    | Tom       | White    |      65123 | 6/4/2017  |    15 |          713.78 |
| SALES    | Tom       | White    |      65123 | 7/31/2017 |   125 |          838.78 |
| SALES    | Tom       | White    |      65123 | 8/19/2017 |   110 |          948.78 |
| SALES    | Tom       | White    |      65123 | 9/7/2017  |    90 |         1038.78 |
| SALES    | Tom       | White    |      65123 | 9/26/2017 |    80 |         1118.78 |
+----------+-----------+----------+------------+-----------+-------+-----------------+
```

Comment: What database are you using?  If you're using MS SQL I would create a function to carry out the logic and pass the two dates in as parameters

Comment: I am using SQL Server management Studio

Comment: Please show some sample data, and expected output. Your current query just UNION two tables, does not seems doing merge to me

Comment: Your code provides no indication of where you want to fiddle with dates. Asides: `UNION`, rather than `UNION ALL`, removes duplicates. Using keywords, e.g. `MERGE` and `DATE`, for objects is not recommended, `case when CustomerDate > SalesDate then SalesDate when CustomerDate = SalesDate then CustomerDate else NULL end` will do something. As you've written it you want to use _both_ values if they are equal!

Comment: SOURCE FIRSTNAME LAST NAME CUSTOMERNO  DATE SALES CUMLATIVE_SALES
CUSTOMER Tom White 65123 3/1/2017 38.78 
CUSTOMER Tom White 65123 3/20/2017 128 166.78
CUSTOMER Tom White 65123 4/8/2017 256 422.78
CUSTOMER Tom White 65123 4/27/2017 105 527.78
CUSTOMER Tom White 65123 5/16/2017 78 605.78
CUSTOMER Tom White 65123 6/4/2017 15 620.78
SALES Tom White 65123 5/16/2017 78 698.78
SALES Tom White 65123 6/4/2017 15 713.78
SALES Tom White 65123 7/31/2017 125 838.78
SALES Tom White 65123 8/19/2017 110 948.78
SALES Tom White 65123 9/7/2017 90 1038.78
SALES Tom White 65123 9/26/2017 80 1118.78

Comment: SOURCE FIRSTNAME LAST NAME CUSTOMERNO  DATE SALES CUMLATIVE_SALES
CUSTOMER Tom White 65123 3/1/2017 38.78 
CUSTOMER Tom White 65123 3/20/2017 128 166.78
CUSTOMER Tom White 65123 4/8/2017 256 422.78
CUSTOMER Tom White 65123 4/27/2017 105 527.78
CUSTOMER Tom White 65123 5/16/2017 78 605.78
CUSTOMER Tom White 65123 6/4/2017 15 620.78
SALES Tom White 65123 7/31/2017 125 745.78
SALES Tom White 65123 8/19/2017 110 855.78
SALES Tom White 65123 9/7/2017 90 945.78
SALES Tom White 65123 9/26/2017 80 1025.78

Comment: Sample 1 need Sample 2

Comment: Katie you need to edit your question and post those samples. You may want to format it with https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ or another site... no one can read that comment and make sense of it unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you're on SQL Server 2012 or later, the following should work for you.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Merge', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #Merge;

CREATE TABLE #Merge (
    SOURCE VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
    FIRSTNAME CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    LASTNAME CHAR(5), 
    CUSTOMERNO INT NOT NULL, 
    [DATE] DATE NOT NULL,
    SALES MONEY NOT NULL, 
    CUMLATIVE_SALES MONEY NOT NULL DEFAULT (0)
    );
SET DATEFORMAT MDY
INSERT #Merge (SOURCE, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, CUSTOMERNO, DATE, SALES) VALUES
    ('CUSTOMER', 'Tom', 'White', 65123, '03/01/2017', 38.78),
    ('CUSTOMER', 'Tom', 'White', 65123, '03/20/2017', 128),
    ('CUSTOMER', 'Tom', 'White', 65123, '04/08/2017', 256), 
    ('CUSTOMER', 'Tom', 'White', 65123, '04/27/2017', 105), 
    ('CUSTOMER', 'Tom', 'White', 65123, '05/16/2017', 78),  
    ('CUSTOMER', 'Tom', 'White', 65123, '06/04/2017', 15),  
    ('SALES',    'Tom', 'White', 65123, '07/31/2017', 125), 
    ('SALES',    'Tom', 'White', 65123, '08/19/2017', 110), 
    ('SALES',    'Tom', 'White', 65123, '09/07/2017', 90),  
    ('SALES',    'Tom', 'White', 65123, '09/26/2017', 80);  
    --('CUSTOMER', 'Tom', 'White', 65123, '3/1/2017 ', 38.78), 
    --('CUSTOMER', 'Tom', 'White', 65123, '3/20/2017',   128), 
    --('CUSTOMER', 'Tom', 'White', 65123, '4/8/2017 ',   256), 
    --('CUSTOMER', 'Tom', 'White', 65123, '04/27/2017',   105), 
    --('CUSTOMER', 'Tom', 'White', 65123, '05/16/2017',    78), 
    --('CUSTOMER', 'Tom', 'White', 65123, '06/04/2017 ',    15), 
    --('SALES', 'Tom', 'White', 65123, '05/16/2017',    78), 
    --('SALES', 'Tom', 'White', 65123, '06/04/2017 ',    15), 
    --('SALES', 'Tom', 'White', 65123, '07/31/2017',   125), 
    --('SALES', 'Tom', 'White', 65123, '08/19/2017',   110), 
    --('SALES', 'Tom', 'White', 65123, '09/07/2017 ',    90), 
    --('SALES', 'Tom', 'White', 65123, '09/26/2017',    80);

--================================================================

WITH
    cte_CUMLATIVE_SALES AS (
        SELECT 
            m.CUMLATIVE_SALES,
            cs = SUM(m.SALES) OVER (PARTITION BY m.CUSTOMERNO ORDER BY m.[DATE])
        FROM
            #Merge m
        )
UPDATE cs SET 
    cs.CUMLATIVE_SALES = cs.cs
FROM
    cte_CUMLATIVE_SALES cs;

SELECT * FROM #Merge m ORDER BY m.[DATE];
```

Results...

```
SOURCE   FIRSTNAME LASTNAME CUSTOMERNO  DATE        SALES                 CUMLATIVE_SALES
-------- --------- -------- ----------- ----------  --------------------- ---------------------
CUSTOMER Tom       White    65123       2017-03-01  38.78                 38.78
CUSTOMER Tom       White    65123       2017-03-20  128.00                166.78
CUSTOMER Tom       White    65123       2017-04-08  256.00                422.78
CUSTOMER Tom       White    65123       2017-04-27  105.00                527.78
CUSTOMER Tom       White    65123       2017-05-16  78.00                 605.78
CUSTOMER Tom       White    65123       2017-06-04  15.00                 620.78
SALES    Tom       White    65123       2017-07-31  125.00                745.78
SALES    Tom       White    65123       2017-08-19  110.00                855.78
SALES    Tom       White    65123       2017-09-07  90.00                 945.78
SALES    Tom       White    65123       2017-09-26  80.00                 1025.78
```